# Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value Mapkit

Tags: annotations, location, mapkit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

```
@IBOutlet var Map: MKMapView!


   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.7, 2.1667)

    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.2, 0.2)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)



let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

 annotation.coordinate=(location)

  annotation.title = "Sant Feliu de Codines"

    Map.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

The error that appears is: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

```
libswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ():
0x2a2d0c <+0>:   push   {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
0x2a2d10 <+4>:   add    r7, sp, #12
0x2a2d14 <+8>:   push   {r8, r10, r11}
0x2a2d18 <+12>:  sub    sp, sp, #40
0x2a2d1c <+16>:  bfc    sp, #0, #3
0x2a2d20 <+20>:  mov    r11, r3
0x2a2d24 <+24>:  mov    r6, r0
0x2a2d28 <+28>:  ldr    r0, [r7, #0xc]
0x2a2d2c <+32>:  ldr    r3, [r7, #0x8]
0x2a2d30 <+36>:  tst    r2, #1
0x2a2d34 <+40>:  bne    0x2a2d58                  ; <+76>
0x2a2d38 <+44>:  cmp    r1, #0
0x2a2d3c <+48>:  blt    0x2a2d80                  ; <+116>
0x2a2d40 <+52>:  str    r0, [sp]
0x2a2d44 <+56>:  add    r1, r6, r1
0x2a2d48 <+60>:  mov    r0, r6
0x2a2d4c <+64>:  mov    r2, r11
0x2a2d50 <+68>:  bl     0x2e7088
; function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded> of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)
```

->  0x2a2d54 <+72>:  trap

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing you need to change is:

```
annotation.coordinate=(location)
```

to:

```
annotation.coordinate = location
```

Otherwise, make sure your IBOutlet is hooked up correctly and that you have no other errors in interface builder.

Comment: The only error that i get is this one and i can't find why does the error come up when I try to launch the app. I think the rest of the interface builder hasn't got any other errors.

Comment: Your problem is one of two things: either your IBOutlet is not properly hooked up to your view in interface builder or your view in interface builder is not of class MKMapView. Basically, what is happening is that Map has a value of nil during viewDidLoad, which triggers your error on the setRegion line.